# how to pass multiple currency event using DTM?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I tried using the sproducts variable along with s.events.

```
var XXXXvalue = 100;
var YYYYvalue = 500;
s.events = "event313,event314";
s.products=";;;;event313=+XXXXvalue|event314=+YYYYvalue";
```

And, in the image request i'm not getting the actual value(100 & 500) on the events respectively instead it appears the below. Any help or thoughts? Thanks
[image request attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW6TH.png)

[image]

Comment: title misleading. Your question isn't really about passing multiple currencies to AA in DTM, but rather a question of basic javascript syntax

Answer (score 1):

javascript does not interpolate variables. Meaning, they do not eval inside quotes. You need to break out of the quotes:

```
var XXXXvalue = 100;
var YYYYvalue = 500;
s.events = "event313,event314";
s.products=";;;;event313="+XXXXvalue+"|event314="+YYYYvalue;
```